# FindSequence of difference equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Coud you calculate the recurrence formula for  $a(k)$ knowing $b(n)$
$$b(n)=\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} a(k) \binom{n-1}{k}-a(n-1)$$
I try to inverter the transformation for $b(n)$.

Comment: Could you use parentheses to make it clear what the argument of your sum is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inversion to obtain sequence $a(k)$ for a given $b(k)$ is a more subtle than applying the binomial transform in this case.  First of all lets get an equivalent expression.  Observe that the last term cancels the last one in the summation.  That means the upper index is $n-2$ and we want an upper index of $n,$ so shift by two units:
$$b(n+2)=\sum_{k=0}^n a(k) \binom{n+1}{k} = (n+1)\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a(k)}{n+1-k} \binom{n}{k}$$
where a recursion for the binomial has been used.  Define $c(n)=b(n+2)/(n+1)$ and reindex the sum to get
$$c(n)= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a(n-k)}{k+1} \binom{n}{k}.$$
Fortunately this is invertible by a formula in Riordan, Combinatorial Identities,Chapter 3, eq.16:
$$c(n)= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a(n-k)}{k+1} \binom{n}{k} \Leftrightarrow 
a(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} B_{n-k}\,c(k)$$
Here the $B_k$ are Bernoulli numbers: $B_0=1, B_1=-1/2, B_2=1/6, ...$

As a check I let $a(k)=k+1$  The sum is solvable in closed form (within the big parenthesis replace the $k$ with $n.$) Thus we end up with the inversion that looks very complicated, but is neat to code up and watch it spit out consecutive integers,
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} B_{n-k}\cdot \Big(\frac{2^k\,k - k + 3\cdot 2^k - 2}{k+1}\Big) =n+1$$

Comment: thanks @skbmoore works fine..well done